# When is Brexit going to happen?

Tags: immigration, eu-spouses, brexit

I am a British citizen and I would like to know when Brexit is going to happen. And when it happens, is the law going to stay the same or going to change? I'm asking this because I want to bring my non-EEA wife to Germany next year.

Comment: Maybe March 2019, maybe later, maybe never.... To follow Brexit from the legal side, I'd suggest following [Jack of Kent](http://jackofkent.com/). The FT is pretty good on un-biased Brexit news too

Comment: @Gagravarr, I suspect it will not truly be that date as well. Asif, there is no guarantee that some EU regulations regarding family rights might or might not remain in force as part of the negotiation. The leanings at this point suggest that situations/rights like yours may remain in place even after formal Brexit. But it is really had to tell at this point and attitudes can change over night.

Answer (score -1):

Theresa May has recently set the approximate date of [March 2017](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjQh-2G0dfPAhUhB8AKHdGODqMQFggiMAE&url=http%3A%2F%2Fmoney.cnn.com%2F2016%2F10%2F02%2Fnews%2Feconomy%2Fbrexit-article-50-theresa-may%2F&usg=AFQjCNGSihzFYvrnsfhKq2_frXqyS5SA1g) to initiate formal proceedings, which means a final exit in March 2019.

Comment: Assuming that giving notice isn't postponed, assuming that the court cases don't require parliamentary debate that delays it, and assuming that post-notice there isn't approval to extend the 2 years + the notice isn't withdrawn (which may or may not be possible...)

Comment: @Gagravarr, and even assuming that they decide to even really go through  with it! Something I don't think is quite certain.